# Identifying a movie from the 80s with one scene about nukes and a fork

Tags: story-identification, movie

There's a movie I remember watching in school, and I only remember one scene.  I hope somebody can identify this.  I'm sorry.

This would have been close to 1990, so I assume it's a movie from the 80s. I remember nothing about the movie other than that it was very boring, except for this one scene. (This is a live-action movie, not animated.)

The main character was a boy and in the only scene I remember, there's a man who I believe was dressed in a fancy military uniform, like a general maybe. The general (or whatever) was describing nuclear weapons to the kid, maybe at school -- I think there were a lot of kids there. He says something to the effect of "If your mother were washing dishes at the sink, and she dropped a fork right when this bomb went off, the fork would never hit the ground".

I feel like the general was taking some kind of sadistic glee in terrifying the kid with this, and had for some reason singled out the protagonist among his peers.

My brain keeps insisting it was *Stand By Me*, but it definitely wasn't that. Maybe that's not helpful, I don't know why I have that connection in my head.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not *War Games* nor *The Manhattan Project*.

Comment: Was it in English, and, if so, which English?

Comment: I just skimmed through The Day After on YouTube and there weren't any scenes like that.

Comment: Did the movie have any science fictional elements? As described, it does not seem to.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if it were _Red Dawn_, which would make it fantasy, not science fiction.

Comment: It was an American movie as far as I know, and I don't think it was scifi or fantasy.  It was more like reflecting the cold war era fears, I think. Or at least that scene was, I don't know if that was the whole film's point.

Comment: If it is not a science fiction or fantasy movie, it is off topic for this site, and outside of our area of expertise.   You'll need to find a site or a group of movie id experts to help you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a science fiction or fantasy work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This movie may be "[Amazing Grace and Chuck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Grace_and_Chuck)". This is not a sci-fi/fantasy; the film is a message about nuclear disarmament. The balance of the story - after the Wikipedia excerpt below - deals with a professional basketball player (Amazing Grace) who joins Chuck's protest, and thereby brings national, then world, attention to the story.[image]

Chuck Murdock (Joshua Zuehlke), a 12-year-old boy from Montana and the son of a military jet pilot, becomes anxious after seeing a Minuteman missile on a school field trip, which is intensified by a nightmare of a fork dropping after being told that the speed and effectiveness would be done "before a dropped fork hits the floor". Chuck protests the existence of nuclear weapons by refusing to play baseball, which results in the forfeit of a Little League game by his team.

Comment: Okay wow, yeah, that must be the one.  That fork thing sounds exactly right. Now that I'm thinking of basketball I think I do remember a scene with a bunch of basketball players and the kid, but I'm not sure it's a memory from the same movie!